# How can I map raster and vector data together?

Tags: r, vector, maps, raster, shapefile

I want to map raster and vector data in R

Data

```
class(Africa)# SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
class(Rift)#SpatialLinesDataFrame
class(Data.SP)#SpatialPointsDataFrame
class(An_Precip_subTest)#RasterLayer`
```

Code I am trying to run

```
tm_shape(Africa) + 
tm_raster(An_Precip_subTest)+
tm_shape(Data.SP) +
tm_dots(col="CS", auto.palette.mapping = FALSE, palette="-RdYlBu",
    breaks=Spectrum, title="Ventral Centroid Size", size=0.3)+
tm_shape(Rift) + tm_lines(col = "black") +
tm_legend(legend.outside=TRUE)
```

I get this error message 
Error: Africa consists of polygons, so it cannot accept tm_raster.

I have modeled my code after the tmap in a nutshell examples
    (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-nutshell.html)

```
tm_shape(land) + 
tm_raster("trees", breaks=seq(0, 100, by=20), legend.show = FALSE) +
tm_shape(Europe, is.master = TRUE) +
tm_borders() +
tm_shape(rivers) +
tm_lines(lwd="strokelwd", scale=5, legend.lwd.show = FALSE) +
tm_shape(metro) +
tm_bubbles("pop2010", "red", border.col = "black", border.lwd=1, 
    size.lim = c(0, 11e6), sizes.legend = c(1e6, 2e6, 4e6, 6e6, 10e6), 
    title.size="Metropolitan Population") +
tm_text("name", size="pop2010", scale=1, root=4, size.lowerbound = .6, 
    bg.color="white", bg.alpha = .75, 
    auto.placement = 1, legend.size.show = FALSE) + 
tm_format_Europe() +
tm_style_natural()
```

They just drop a raster file in after a shape file and everything works out fine.
I do not understand how my code is different and incorrect.
I used this example 
    (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61243/clipping-a-raster-in-r) to make my raster file
I wonder if others have had trouble recreating this example

How can I map raster and vector data together?
I am up for trying new packages, converting data to different formats etc 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Although an old question. But maybe the solution is helpful for other people. To plot the vector (shape file overlaid with raster), first run `tm_raster()` + `tm_shape` (your shapefile (`sp,sf object)`) + `tm_dots` (in case your shape file is points object)